# Inherited Class works even when Base Class Assembly is Missing

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Sorry, I'm being vague because it's a question related to some stuff at work that's IP restricted.

I have a class in an assembly by itself (Assembly A) that inherits from a generic base class that's in another assembly (Assembly B). This base class has a static method that is used as an entry point to the "application" that the inheriting class is implemented.

The static method is implemented in Assembly B. There's a pluggable application that launches the contents of Assembly A at runtime, reflectively. When I run this application, Assembly A seems to work fine for a little bit, but then crashes when it can't find Assembly B. I expect this. Assembly B is not currently available anywhere on the machine.

Order of execution:

1. The Launcher application is started via Command Line, with the DLL containing Assembly A referenced by file path.
2. The Launcher application reflectively finds the magic static method that's implemented in Assembly B, even though it only has access to Assembly A. (Assembly B is nowhere to be found on the machine. No GAC, no files.)
3. The static method works (and successfully uses other Types in Assembly B) for a short while.
4. An exception is thrown when the execution of Launcher finally comes across a Type from Assembly B that it couldn't find.

What I don't understand, and the internet isn't telling me (lots of searching), is how Assembly A works for a little while when the code that initially executes is implemented in Assembly B. What does the .NET compiler (or potentially Roslyn, since I'm using that in VS2015) include in Assembly A from Assembly B that allows it to function for a little bit? Is this deterministic? What's going on here?

Comment: Your description is vague too, so I could hardly comment. About how such a program runs, you can easily dig the MSIL and also live debug. Post some code might also help. Just don't ask every reader to guess what's up.

Comment: You are simply witnessing the just-in-time behavior of the Just In Time compiler.  Which asks for assemblies just in time.  Hard to see how you are going to do anything differently now that you know this.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm aware that the CLR performs JIT compilation at runtime. I'm saying that it's executing far further than I expect it to be able to without having Assembly B, since the code that's running until it crashes is implemented in Assembly B. I expect the missing assembly exception to occur basically immediately, yet it still manages to execute for a while.

Comment: Those types from assembly B that are being used successfully, how are they being used? How is the type that causes the exception being used and what's difference between it and the other types? How are the assemblies compiled and what are the compiler options being used?